# wordpress display pages

Tags: wordpress

I use plugin [wp-type](http://wp-types.com/)

The **wp-type plugin** is used for making custom pages.
You can add for example a new field of type "file" and display the filelink in the page with the following code :

```
<?php
echo(types_render_field("file", array("title"=>"Download", "link"=>"true")));
?>
```

My problem is when I try to display files : in the main page everything's ok, but when I try to display the list of the posts with index.php it doesn't work.

This problem appears only with pages for posts I use :

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
echo(types_render_field("file", array("title"=>"Download", "link"=>"true")));
endwhile;?>
```

and it works well.

Please help me to display all pages in index.php and each page file I try this :

```
<?php while (wp_list_pages( ));
echo(types_render_field("file", array("title"=>"Download", "link"=>"true")));
endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Replace your code to display page list:**

```
 while (wp_list_pages( )); to while (wp_list_pages( )):
```